# getting specific table rows based on the value within an input being greater than zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the number of rows in a table where an input within the row has a value greater than zero. so for example i have

```
<table>
 <tr><td><input type="text" value="23.4"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="text" value="39.5"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="text" value="14.4"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="text" value="0"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="text" value="89"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

so the query must return a total row count of 4 using the above example.

I have managed to get the following to work as the quickest and easiest solution to this problem

```
var counter = 0;
$('table tr').each(function(){
   if(parseFloat($(this).find('input').val()) > 0){counter++;}
});
```

the value increments for each value found greater than zero. thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2):

Get the rows, then filter on inputs that you filter on wether they have a value greater than zero.

```
var numb = $('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('input').filter(function() {
        return this.value > 0;
    }).length > 0;
}).length;
```

This would allow mulitple inputs in each row, and if any input has a value greater than zero, the row is counted

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g0y0n248/)

Comment: `this.value > 0`? Do you not need to cast to a number from the usual value-string?

Comment: @DavidThomas - Not if the value is numeric, the `>` and `<` operators handle that

Comment: Ah, I'd never realised that; I always assumed it would lead to a lexicographical sort. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @DavidThomas - It's a litte confusing, given that the mathematical operators, especially `+` would cause issues, but the "greater than" and "lesser than" operators actually automagically convert to a number.

Answer (score 1):

well you need jQuery, then retrieve all '.tr input', then check the value

```
var res = $('tr input').filter(function(index){
   // need multiplicate by 1 to cast as number because input values are always strings
   return (this.value*1) > 0;
});
console.log('res.length : ', res.length);
```